# Brain Teaser Incomplete?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

I am uncertain regarding what this question is specifically asking?

"the columns of M form Michael's Basis, and the column Z form Zan's basis. If A is the matrix representation of transformation **T** in Michael's basis, what is the matrix representation of transformation **T** in Zan's basis"

I am assuming the name's Michael and Zan are distinct matrices. However, since I don't understand the relationship between the two matrices, Michael and Zan, as there appears to be none, would the solution just be A as well...It seems a bit trivial.

Comment: But you do know something about change of basis don't you?

Comment: This is about how change of basis affects the matrix representation of operators. You actually have _three_ bases here: Michael's, Zan's and _ours_ (the one you use to express the columns of $M$ and $Z$). You want to know how to transform the matrix representation of an operator in Michael's basis to its matrix representation in Zan's.

Comment: Are you familier with basis 'transition' matrices? You should use these to Pre/Post Multiply$A $ (as appropriate)

Comment: @Arthur so then would the matrix representation of the transformation simply be its inverse? So A^-1

Comment: @AnyAD. How would I undo the matrix operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix $M$ is the change-of-basis matrix from Michael's basis to the standard basis, whereas $Z$ is the change-of-basis from Zen's basis to the standard basis. Therefore, $Z^{-1}M$ is the change-of-basis matrix from Michael's basis to Zen's. So, the answer to your question is $$Z^{-1}MA(Z^{-1}M)^{-1}(=Z^{-1}MAM^{-1}Z).$$